# List of local:MvxBind binders

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I couldn't find a list of all type of binders available for use, recently a collegue found about local:MvxBind="Visibility Property" and that helped a lot with our code. I belive that MvvMCross has a lot of hidden gems that we don't know yet. Is the information available somewhere?

Binders that we know:

- local:MvxBind="Text Property"
- local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Property; SelectedItem Property"
- local:MvxBind="Click ICommandProperty"
- local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Property; ItemClick ICommandProperty"
- local:MvxBind="Visibility Property"

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Automatic Property Binding

MvvmCross binds to C# properties on native Views - so any public C# get/set property exposed by Xamarin.Android can be one-way bound to.

Further, if the property `Foo` is accompanied by an event of signature `public event EventHandler FooChanged` then MvvmCross can two-way bind to it.

---

#### Automatic Event Binding

MvvmCross also binds to any `public` C# `event`s which are exposed by native views - as long as they have `EventHandler` signatures and **not** `EventHandler<SomeSpecialArgs>`

These can be automatically bound to `ICommand` callers (the action is automatically bound to the `Execute` handler, but **nothing** is automatically bound to the `CanExecute`).

---

#### Custom Binding

Beyond these straight-forward properties, MvvmCross also has facilities for "custom bindings".

The list of "custom bindings" that MvvmCross supplied by default is in `FillTargetBindings` in AndroidBindingBuilder - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L79

```
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("Text",
                                                        textView => new MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding(textView));
        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory((typeof(MvxAutoCompleteTextViewPartialTextTargetBinding)),
                                                typeof(AutoCompleteTextView), "PartialText");
        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
                                                typeof(MvxAutoCompleteTextViewSelectedObjectTargetBinding),
                                                typeof(AutoCompleteTextView),
                                                "SelectedObject");
        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof(MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding),
                                                typeof(CompoundButton), "Checked");
        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof(MvxSeekBarProgressTargetBinging), typeof(SeekBar),
                                                "Progress");
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>("Visible",
                                                        view => new MvxViewVisibleBinding(view));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>("Hidden",
                                                        view => new MvxViewHiddenBinding(view));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>("Bitmap",
                                                        imageView => new MvxImageViewBitmapTargetBinding(imageView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>("DrawableId",
                                                        imageView => new MvxImageViewDrawableTargetBinding(imageView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>("DrawableName",
                                                        imageView => new MvxImageViewDrawableNameTargetBinding(imageView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>("AssetImagePath",
                                                         imageView => new MvxImageViewImageTargetBinding(imageView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<MvxSpinner>("SelectedItem",
                                                                         spinner =>
                                                                         new MvxSpinnerSelectedItemBinding(
                                                                             spinner));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<AdapterView>("SelectedItemPosition",
                                                                          adapterView =>
                                                                          new MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemPositionTargetBinding
                                                                              (adapterView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<MvxListView>("SelectedItem",
                                                                          adapterView =>
                                                                          new MvxListViewSelectedItemTargetBinding
                                                                              (adapterView));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<RatingBar>("Rating",
                                                        ratingBar => new MvxRatingBarRatingTargetBinding(ratingBar));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>("LongClick",
                                                        view =>
                                                        new MvxViewLongClickBinding(view));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<MvxRadioGroup>("SelectedItem",
            radioGroup => new MvxRadioGroupSelectedItemBinding(radioGroup));
```

A couple of the plugins (notably `Color`) also add their own bindings.

For information on adding your own custom bindings, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n28-custom-bindings-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

The N+1 topics on MvvmCross custom controls, on animation and on maps are also worth watching - they provide alternative mechanisms to custom bindings.

For more on MvvmCross binding, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Comment: I'm not sure how this list is representing "default" binding as I can't see basic bindings such as "Click", "TextChanged", etc. I had the same question today and was wondering if there is a systematic way to discover existing bindings. One of my primary goal when coding is to migrate most of the viewcontroller code into the viewModel, so knowing the binding on the tip of my fingers matters a lot.

Comment: They come under the same type of catch-all as `any public C# get/set property exposed by Xamarin.Android can be one-way bound to.` - I'll change the text in the question to assist.